# Loop solver across worksheets using Macro

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach, solver

my limited knowledge knew I could use For Each loop to go through all the worksheets of a workbook and I could record solver as a macro script. However, when I was trying to combine these two methods together to activate and run the solver for each sheet, it doesn't work properly(it works sometimes but not across all sheets, or sometimes it doesn't work at all). There is no control or feedback on why this code works on some sheets rather than all sheets. For the worksheets that worked, when I check the constraints, there are 18(number of my worksheets) same '$J$4:$J$5 <=1' conditions instead of only one condition for each worksheet. Is there a way to improve this situation? Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
Sub Solver()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("A.xlsx")
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In wb.Worksheets

SolverOk SetCell:="$J$8", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$J$4:$J$5", _
Engine:=1, EnineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$4:$J$5", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"

SolverOk SetCell:="$J$8", MaxMinVal:=2,Valueof:=0, ByChange:="$J$4:$J$5", _
Engine:=3, EnineDesc:="Evolutionary"
SolverOk SetCell:="$J$8", MaxMinVal:=2,Valueof:=0, ByChange:="$J$4:$J$5", _
Engine:=3, EnineDesc:="Evolutionary"

SolverSolve True

Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through (F8 in the VBE) your Solver routine to see if the code behaves as expected? If not I'd step through each iteration of the `For...Next` and check what the code is doing along with what's happening on the target worksheet.

Comment: Hi @SamuelEverson, no, I haven't done that yet. I will check with F8. Thank you for suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week-long investigation and trying various codes. I finally noticed that it is the user form that makes adding constraints command failed. After manually remove these user forms, the code runs perfectly and provides the feedback I need. If someone has a similar issue, please check if there is any unusual add-on in your worksheets.